Just found thick orange roots buried next to my house
I've just exposed some thick orange roots next to my house. They look exactly like pictures I've seen of Osage Orange. Are these invasive in NJ?
Unfortunately I don't have pictures of what was on my property. I dug up the roots and threw them out. However they looked exactly like this


Do you have an osage orange on or near your property?
